# soap ui call for .net soap service success but fails with http 500 in ksoap2 android

Tags: android, soap, service, call, ksoap2

this is the service method

SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/LogInUser"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LogInUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <us>
        <UserName>string</UserName>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <CityName>string</CityName>
        <DistrictOneName>string</DistrictOneName>
        <DistrictTwoName>string</DistrictTwoName>
        <DistrictThreeName>string</DistrictThreeName>
        <BloodType>string</BloodType>
        <Phone>string</Phone>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <Surname>string</Surname>
      </us>
    </LogInUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

this is the how I call it in android that fails with IOException and HTTP 500 error yet,

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        SoapObject user = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "us");                         
        user.addProperty("UserName", us.UserName);
        user.addProperty("Password", us.Password);
        user.addProperty("CityName", "?");
        user.addProperty("DistrictOneName","?");
        user.addProperty("DistrictTwoName","?");
        user.addProperty("DistrictThreeName", "?");
        user.addProperty("BloodType", "?");
        user.addProperty("Phone", "?");
        user.addProperty("Name", "?");
        user.addProperty("Surname", "?");
        request.addSoapObject(user);

        Log.d(TAG, request.toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

I have done well in soap ui call.

Comment: well using latest build of ksoap2 lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `us` should be an instance of the `LogInUser` class, which needs to implement **`KVMSerializable`**.

Have a look at the **[documentation](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives)** for detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks but offical web is bit of non related to complex types hence I found it here http://seesharpgears.blogspot.de/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

Comment: Well, in the official documentation they *DO* talk about KVMSerializable. Anyway, the tutorial you found does pretty much the same thing. I am glad that you got it working. Cheers! :)